# Error while opening PDF document created through Future method

Tags: apex, webservices, pdf, future, asynchronous

I have a webservice class 'restExample' which first performs DML operations and then calls a future method 'createDocument()'. This method will create PDF document. One important point: Running user is a guest user with user license `Guest License`

`restExample:`

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/restExample')
global class MyRestContextExample{

@HttpPost
global static void getPara () {

   //performs DML operations on multiple salesforce objects.
   simulate.createDocument(); 
   //'simulate' is the class name and 'createDocument' is the future method.
}
```

Reason behind using future method is : `createDocument()` will also perform a callout which will use records that gets updated in `restExample` webservice class.

`Future Class: simulate`

```
public class simulate{

@future(callout=true)
public static void createDocument(){
  // code that generates PDF document.
}
}
```

A PDF document is getting successfully generated but it is throwing error when opened.

`Error in chrome:`
[image]

`Error in Adobe Reader`

[image]

When I execute future method `createDocument()` from `anonymous window` in `Developer Console` , PDF gets generated correctly and also able to open properly. Hence the code in `createDocument()` method works correctly.

NOTE: I am aware of the fact that I am not providing lot of code in the question. Three Reasons for the this: 1) All the DML operations are happening correctly and future method gets called in a seperate context.
2)Future method IS INFACT creating PDF. 
3) PDF generation is happening with managed class,I just call that class in future method and code in managed class is hidden ..

Comment: @SantanuBoral Are you referring to callout to `restExample` webservice OR the callout performed in future method.

Comment: Are you performing this action from visualforce? anyone of above

Comment: Yes, PDF does get generated through visualforce. I will not be able to post that code since that particular VF page is a part of managed package. Also, Since I am able to generate PDF properly through `anonymous window` in Developer Console, I am assuming VF is working correctly.

Comment: Is that other callout is generated from visualforce?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: One Point that I missed is : running user is a guest user' with license `Guest License`. I will add this in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed package class is using `getContentAsPDF` to generate the PDF, am sorry to say 
it will always be blank/corrupted in guest user context.

The reason being, In the managed package they have used this below code to generate PDF

```
PageReference ref = Page.MyPage;
 Blob b = ref.getContentAsPDF();

 Insert new Attachment(ParentId='0069E00000790ok',body=b,Name='my.pdf');
```

For PDF to generate in guest user context following conditions should be met for Valid generation

1. Pagereference should be made with full URL to VF page

   PageReference ref = new PageReference('https://mysite.cs88.force.com/MyPage');
2. Your class should be without sharing.
3. Guest User profile should have Access to VF Page and Apex Class used
4. That VF Page should be Publicly accessible via guest site user(Public user)

That being said, if above conditions are met, you will be able to generate proper PDF, from Guest user profile, this would mean you have to ask you managed partner client to edit these changes for you.

Is there any other option other than asking manged package guys to edit code?

Yes there is, but it will get ugly (warning)

From your RestApi apex controller

1. Do a Rest login call to get access token(session id) of Admin(Automated User). Using oauth2 Rest call to get access token of Admin User. You need to use Username and Password stored in custom setting/metadata. 
   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm
2. Use Tooling API to call execute anonymous code, with sessionID received from step one. 
   https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009FJ6IAM
3. Once you do that tooling api rest call, it will be as good as running executeAnon in admin user context. You will get your PDF. Its sort of replicating session of ADMIN user in guest user context.

Source: [getContentAsPDF menance for Guest user](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000005HYsIAM)

Comment: Thanks @Pranay. This does provide insights to the problem. I have queries on possible workarounds. As you have mentioned `Pagereference should be made with full URL to VF page` -- This should be done in VF page in managed package?

Comment: Also @Pranay, Can you provide some more details for any example for the workaround `From your RestApi apex controller

1) Do a Rest login call to get access token(session id) of Admin(Automated User)
2) Use Tooling API to call execute anonymous code, with sessionID received from step one.
3) See pdf being generated`

Comment: Hi I have updated the answer with Links , do let me know if you have any issues.. we can discuss more in chat.

Comment: Hi @Pranay, Can we discuss more about the 2nd Solution . I am facing some issues in building that. Let me know if we can chat.

Comment: Lets chat here.
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77561/error-while-opening-pdf-document-created-through-future-method

Comment: Hi @Pranay, I am in the chat room and I have posted my question over there.